# How do I grab an m3u8 link under Chrome "Inspect" > "Network"? (Using Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My goal is to grab the m3u8 link. I open the webpage and start the video, hit Inspect > Network, and I see the desired link.

The link does NOT appear under "View page source".

How would I grab this link using Selenium?

[image]

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: There is no css, no xpath. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: The link you are referring is a XHR request to a web server. It has nothing to do with DOM elements. You might be able to use a proxy and intercept the request to get the endpoint url it targets.